# Variables within VBA formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling to achieve the exact outcome I want.

Below is a formula that the macro recorder created, which is fine to an extent - however my issue is the sheet I wish to import from isn't always going to be called Week 11. It will however always be 'Sheet1' as far as VBA is concerned in that particular workbook.

In my example we have the main workbook (BookA), and the report (Week x.csv)

Currently you can choose which week you want to import from a drop down box, this opens the corresponding file when the import button is pressed.

How can I amend this VBA so that it will correctly import from whichever report is opened (Week 1, Week 2 etc)

My current variable is 'week'.

Hope you can help

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=COUNTIFS('Week 11.csv'!C10,R2C&""*"",'Week 11.csv'!C11,""NC recd*"")"
```

Comment: Put the chosen week from the dropdown box into a variable and concatenate it to the rest of the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim x as long
for x = 1 to 11
    cells(x,1).formular1c1 = "=countifs('week " & x & ".csv'!c10,r2C&""*"", 'week " & x & ".csv'!c11,""NC NC recd*"")"
next x
```

Comment: I have amended this, it works thank you - I just wanted to ask a quick question. In the middle of the code you have 'r2C' in reference to a cell that is one of my criteria for the countif - what is this syntax? Once the data is counted I am moving the formulas along to another column where the criteria would change

Comment: @OliEshmade, actually I do not know.  I just copy your codes and paste.